# Clustering time series based on calculated distance

Tags: c#, time-series, cluster-analysis

I have many times series with different length, I want to cluster theme into groups based on calculated distance.

I know how to calculate distance (DTW or other distance measures) between two times series but how can I applied distance measurements in a lots of time series.

Comment: Which language are you using? You could construct a pair-wise correlation (or distance) matrix between your measurements. In R, this can be done via `cor` or `dist` functions. Alternatively, check `pdist` in matlab.

Comment: I'm using c# as a programming language.

Comment: I wrote a class in Python and tried to explain in another question. You can check at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52542415/6401202